# Delete invalid excel file resource in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I tried reloading the model and exporting a fresh copy but cant delete this old referenced excel file. How can I delete it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the little circle there is red, it means that this file is referenced somewhere in your model but the file doesn't exist. If you erase this reference, wherever it is, it will disappear from there.

But sometimes, AnyLogic gets dumb and keeps the reference (somewhere internally i guess) and then there's nothing you can do about it... I would say it's a bug.

So that's the thing... If you find the reference, erase it (some excel object somewhere in your model)... but if it doesn't work, then you have to live with it.